# Specs on a job say Metalness & Specular workflow maps needed - aren't these 2 different/opposing workflows?

Tags: materials, uv, workflow, image

I am taking a test for a job, and upon receiving the specs, I have come upon some things I don't understand regarding the materials instructions.

The instructions say, "Metalness & Specular workflow maps needed." Has anyone seen this before? I thought it was generally one or another. Prior instructions (before committing to the test) had said "PBR Metalness workflow." The test file (same for everyone doing PBR, it looks like) is a single leather pattern (pretty sure it's a basic BaseColor image).
Doesn't the instruction quoted above suggest that more is needed? If so, does it mean that I am to generate my own out of the image I was given? Of each of these named maps? (If so, I have a lot of work to do.)

I think the relevant specs are as follows:

- Model scale: real world, 1 unit = 1 meter
- Texel density should be 1600 pixels/meter
- Only square textures, 4096x4096 resolution
- Metalness & Specular workflow maps needed
- Main textures:

  - BaseColor (sRGB)
  - AO (Linear)
  - Roughness (Linear)
  - Metalness (Linear)
  - Normal (RGB)
  - Opacity (Linear)
  - Emissive (sRGB)
- Additional textures: Glossiness, Specular
- Normal maps baked from hi-poly models
- OpenGL tangent space Normal map
- Texture names should be: BaseColor, AO, Roughness, Metalness, Glossiness, Specular, Normal, Opacity, Emissive

The leather image file itself is another thing. It's not cut to the pattern, has a very randomly-margined white border. And it is certainly not 4096x4096 resolution. So that I don't understand, either. Am I supposed to crop it? Does it sound right that this would be part of the test?

I have some prior 3d modeling experience from years ago, and plenty of CG experience, but am fairly new to Blender. Gained a lot of experience in the past few months, thought this test would be easy for me. The project itself should be, but I'm confused on the specs now that I'm locked into this test.
I have other questions related to the specs, but I guess I should start here.

Comment: Hello :). A little OT: Just ask them. You obviously know well what you're doing, but you'd be surprised how little might they know :). The test might have been put together by some intern. Don't guess. Show your expertise by requesting more specific information. Good luck :).

Comment: Thank you for your confidence! I actually don't know as much as I sound like I do. I'm teaching myself by tutorials, and only looked up what PBR Metalness workflow was when I saw it in the pre-test instructions. Are you familiar with Metalness & Specular workflow, and whether it makes sense to be asked to use both? Otherwise, I'm thinking it's a typo, which I can ask Support, but I don't want to sound ignorant to the employer.

Comment: This isn't the best place for a discussion :) Feel free to hit me on chat, or Twitter.
Meanwhile - you can check CGcookie explaining Metalness/Specular workflow in Blender, and why materials come with both variants https://youtu.be/mrNMpqdNchY